# How to fix misalignment between image and plot in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf

My goal is to show a binary image and then plot the boundary contours as lines overlaying the image.  If I do this and export the result as a PDF, I see a progressively worsening misalignment between the image and contours as one moves across the image from bottom left.  So it seems like there is a multiplicative error in the position of either the background image or the contours.

I think the issue is caused by the PDF renderer.  If I output the result in PNG with a very high DPI, I can remove the problem, but I would prefer PDF for other reasons.  Does anyone know if there is a setting I can change to make the PDF render correctly?

Here is an example and the resulting image.  You can see that the bottom left corner has good alignment between image and contour and the top right is the worst.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

# Make a test image
img = np.zeros((100,100), dtype=np.uint8)
img[20:99,1:80] = 1
img = np.matlib.repmat(img, 9, 6)

# Extract contours
cntrs, hier = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Make overlay
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,9), dpi=300)
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.imshow(img, interpolation='none', cmap=plt.cm.gray)
for cntr in cntrs:
    x = np.append(cntr[:, 0, 0], cntr[0, 0, 0])
    y = np.append(cntr[:, 0, 1], cntr[0, 0, 1])
    ax.plot(x, y, c='r', linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.7)
ax.axis('off')

# Save overlay
plt.savefig('test.pdf', dpi=fig.dpi)
```

[image]

Comment: I've used high dpi values (at least 1200, but I think I tried higher as well), but it didn't make any difference for PDF rendering.

Comment: Use `ax.imshow(img, interpolation='bilinear', cmap=plt.cm.gray)` with bilinear interpolation instead of None. That gave me nice sharp lines without space around edges using the same dpi.

Comment: Have you thought of drawing the contours with OpenCV on the image and then save the image as PDF?

Comment: @EsraaAbdelmaksoud, my current workaround is to draw the contours by modifying image pixels.  It gives accurate results since it means I am dealing with only a single image, but it can get a bit ugly depending on the image resolution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`pgf`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_pgf_api.html#module-matplotlib.backends.backend_pgf) backend instead of the default `pdf` backend:

```
plt.savefig('test.pdf', dpi=fig.dpi, backend='pgf')
```

This gives the correct pdf identical to the png file: [link to the generated pdf file](https://gofile.io/d/9FPy4i):

[image]

---

The reason for the mismatch is the different scaling of the image: while the difference of the red line positions between pdf and pgf backends is 2.6 µm maximum (i.e. not visually discernible), the image sizes differ by about 0.3 mm:

pdf: 115.358 x 172.861 mm with bottom left corner at 20.574 / 28.575 mm,
pgf: 115.057 x 172.606 mm with bottom left corner at 20.574 / 28.606 mm.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty workaround would be to blow up the figsize. I introduced a scaling factor for this purpose at the beginning of the script. I also increased the original linewidth to 0.6 because it looked a bit nicer. The .pdf looks pretty nice

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.matlib
import cv2
scale = 15
# Make a test image
img = np.zeros((100,100), dtype=np.uint8)
img[20:99,1:80] = 1
img = np.matlib.repmat(img, 9, 6)

# Extract contours
cntrs, hier = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Make overlay
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6*scale,9*scale), dpi=300//scale)
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.imshow(img, interpolation='none', cmap=plt.cm.gray)
for cntr in cntrs:
    x = np.append(cntr[:, 0, 0], cntr[0, 0, 0])
    y = np.append(cntr[:, 0, 1], cntr[0, 0, 1])
    ax.plot(x, y, c='r', linewidth=0.6*scale, alpha=0.7)
ax.axis('off')

# Save overlay
plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

[Here the upper right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqrJd.png)

Comment: Did you decide on a scale factor based on trial-and-error, or is there a theoretical basis for its value?  I want my result to be quantitatively accurate (i.e., I want all the objects in the final image to appear where they actually belong), so I'm a little wary of heuristic solutions in this case.

Comment: This was purely trial-and-error.